# How to send French Characters in PHP CURL POST request?

Tags: php, curl

I have French message in $sms variable and that I need to send it but I am getting error & while I using some English text, it will work fine. How to send French message in Curl PHP.

I have used "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"

below is my code:

```
$sms='{"text":{"fr":"Bienvenue sur Gamebar! Accédez au service et gérer votre abonnement sur"}} '; 

$ordered_params = array(
        
        'order' => '112423',
        'prompt_content_args'=>$sms
        );

        $to_sign = '';
        foreach ($ordered_params as $v)
        { 
        $to_sign .= $v;
        }

        // maybe use utf8_encode($to_sign) if your php file is encoded iso-8859-1
        $digest = hash_hmac('sha256', $to_sign, '8awIiFHqV8zlimG'); 


        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://url.com", // no real
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "digest=$digest&order=112423&prompt_content_args=$sms",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
          ),
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: `I am getting error `...would you like to tell us exactly what the error is, please? Otherwise it's quite hard to help.

Comment: Why not send them just like any other character?

Comment: @ADyson SHA-256 digest is invalid - please use concatenation of unencoded parameter-values alphabetically sorted by parameter-name. This is the error from partner side & they told us that issue because of french message.

Comment: And they won't tell you **why** this happens? How should anybody else know why their validation fails?

Comment: This is honestly a question your partner should answer.

Comment: That's a bit vague. It's not really "French" characters as such I would expect, but maybe non-ASCII characters. Sounds like they have an issue with support for ut8 perhaps. Seems pretty silly that they wouldn't support the ability to send such characters though.

Comment: You need to make sure that your text is encoded as UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1 or cp1252. The quick way to check would be to dump it out as hex, and if the accented chars are represented by a single byte, it's not UTF-8. Do _not_ get in the habit of blindly calling `utf8_encode()` on things, as it _only_ converts from ISO-8859-1 and will happily ruin your input if it's anything else. Use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding) and explicitly specify the input encoding.

Answer (score 2):

There are more problems in that code than could be addressed in comments:

```php
$sms_data = [
    "text" => [
        // make sure that this is UTF-8 encoded _beforehand_. Check your editor's settings and/or source data.
        "fr" => "Bienvenue sur Gamebar! Accédez au service et gérer votre abonnement sur"
    ]
];
$sms = json_encode($sms_data);

$ordered_params = [
    'order' => '112423',
    'prompt_content_args' => $sms
];

$to_sign = '';
foreach ($ordered_params as $v) { 
    $to_sign .= $v;
}

$digest = hash_hmac('sha256', $to_sign, '8awIiFHqV8zlimG'); 

// consistent data structure
$curl_data = [
    'digest' => $digest,
    'order' => 112423,
    'prompt_content_args' => $sms
];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://url.com", // no real
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_POST => true, // why on earth were you using CUSTOMREQUEST?
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $curl_data, // let curl handle the encoding
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    ],
]
);
```

If, for some reason, you need to url-encode a set of parameters outside of a cURL call, you would want to use [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query).